# reading a file from outside webapp container in groovy

Tags: groovy, web-applications

Hi I am trying to read an xml file from outside the web-app container, It works fine when the xml file is in a directory inside the web-app container but doesnt work when I try to access it from a directory location outside web-app. 
I am actually writing the XML file successfully before I try to read it, in any appropriate location in the disk.
I tried paths like c:/xmls/my1.xml, /myprojhome/xmls/my1.xml but only /myprjhome/js/my1.xml works since js directory is inside web-ap.

I am just trying to access by hardcoding the path in the code right now, like 
map.setDataURL("/myprjhome/js/my1.xml"); - this works but others dont, they give data error - not able to find file

Its a windows system I am working on right now, do I need to set the url for the map in some other way? (for eg. using file.seperator)

*I am Using Fusion Maps - a flash based map chart tool which accepts data in xml format, so I import a javascript file which is FusionMaps.js , and this has all the functions like setDataURL inside it.   I am doing this in the javascript to render the chart :*

```
          <script> 
var  map = new FusionMaps("/gra/swf/Maps/FCMap_World.swf", "Map1Id", "750", "400", "0", "0"); 
     map.SetDataURL(URL of the dataxml);
         </script>
```

*The chart shows the map only if the URL is valid, else it shows invalid URL error, I tried to use the File protocol (File:///c:/cmls/mtxml.xml) but it doesnt work. Is it because of the Flash sandbox security model not allowing access to resources outside a domain of the swf file? since you can see that the swf file is located in some other path.. (that path is in web-app..)*

Comment: You mean you want people to be able to click a link and download the xml file from outside of the webapp?  Or is this trying to load the file from inside a controller or something on the server?

Comment: I am just trying to access it internally, load the xml file into the controller, right now the path which I give should be a valid URL , how can I give a path like "C:/xmls/myxml.xml" or on unix like "/usr/documents/.../myxml.xml" , right now its working only if the path when appended to the application url becomes a valid URL location on the system, do I need to give like file:\\\c:/... as the url?

Comment: what is 'map'? I see you see calling 'setDataURL' on it, but your question is lacking this bit of information...

Comment: added the info into the original question.thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so after our conversation in the comments, we finally discover the cause of your problems.

You are doing this in Javascript, so it is on the client side. The client machine cannot see an arbitrary path on your computer (can you imagine the implications if it could?)

You have 2 options:

1. Put the xml inside your webapp (you know this works)
2. Write a server that will return xml from an arbitrary folder when executed.

Would go with #1 unless you have very strong reasons for #2

Comment: well yeah ... I think we dont need the second option for right now, Thanks so much for your help in clearing out this issue..

Comment: A little help here. In my case XML file will be written periodically by the server based on changes in the database values, I cannot place my XML file inside the webapp so how do I write a server to return my XML?

Comment: @shyamnathan when you get a request for the file, open a reader to the file, send the data to the response, and close the reader?